# Create wireframe for 3D LED lamp?

Tags: wireframe

I am new to blender and have a question on how to import a stl file and then edit it's wireframe so that it can be laser engraved on acrylic. Similar to to photo below, how can I adjust x,y,z axis wires as needed?

Thanks all

[image: sample]

Comment: you mean to make this into a 2D lamp, like these? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgLrkWbLCF4

Comment: Hi Luciano, Correct. How can I make wireframe of any imported stl file to look like this so that I can export as SVG and engrave?